# Python script error during normal execution but not during debugging

Tags: python, xhtml2pdf

I have a python 2.7 script that is using the xhtml2pdf library to export from .html to .pdf

The script runs fine when I run it from either IDLE or Visual Studio 2013. However when I try to execute it from a dos window or from a scheduled task I get the error:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The line of code that trows the error is :

```
                import xhtml2pdf.pisa as pisa
                pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(
                    file( TargetFileDest + "\\" + target_file + ".html", "r"),
                    file( TargetFileDest + "\\" + target_file + ".pdf", "wb"),
                    log_warn = 1,
                    log_err = 1,
                    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),  TargetFileDest + "\\" + target_file + ".html")
                    )
```

The error seems to be a unicode problem but I don't know how to debug it if I can't get the error to occur in debug mode. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this before. Whats happening is that IDLE and VS both have different character sets (UTF-8 I think) than command line, which uses ASCII.

try running `chcp 65001` before starting the python program in the command line, see if that works.

Comment: Same result unfortunately

Comment: Other things I would try; change 'r' to 'rb', and insert `decoded_str = html.decode("windows-1252")
encoded_str = decoded_str.encode("utf8")`

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. Where would I add the decode and encode statements? Do I have to do them on the html file I open?

Comment: That depends on exactly where the error is happening; the decode and encode should happen before the action that causes the "can't decode".

Comment: I decoded from uft-8 with the ignore option and then encoded back. The resulting file seems fine, no funky characters, and again works great in debug mode but still fails when run from the command line. I also tried setting sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8') in the script. Again this works fine from an IDE but fails when run from command line. This time the error mentions the eft-8 codec instead of the ascii codec. Any other suggestions?

Comment: At this point, the only other thing I can think of is that its using some other codec. I would see if you can poke around in IDLE to see what codec its using when you run your program.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Tyler. I think I might try a different python compiler, something like IronPython and see if that makes a difference.